# Mongodb NoSQL group, match queries with springboot jpa

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, jpa, nosql

How to call the below query with spring boot java ?[mongodb query to group a collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN9VJ.png)

Comment: Did you try `JpaSpecification`? on jpa specifications you can create complex query

Comment: Kindly see this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-projections-aggregations.  You will need to create an aggregation and group based on your query.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/977919

Comment: Welcome to So.  When posting a question, please don't [post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1256234).